# File closes automatically

Tags: c++, linux

I am encountering a problem when I am trying to write to sysfs node.
In the below code I am trying to wite to a **trace_marker** file. In the ftrace log, the first write is successful. But after that the write fails.
The file descriptor seemingly closes.

I do not want to open file every time before writing as writes are too frequent.

```
class Logger {

int mFileFd;

void logFromAnotherThread(std::string s) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mLogMu);
    ...
    int count = write(mFileFd, s.c_str(), s.length());
    if (count > 0)
       std::cout << "Wrote n bytes: " << count << std::endl;
    else
       std::cout << "Errornum: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    ...
}


Logger() {
   mFileFd = open(SYSFS_NODE_WRITE,  O_WRONLY);
   ....
}

}
```

First write is succesful.

I get output as-
**Errornum: Bad file descriptor**

My expectation is file open should be once, file descrtiptor should remain open for entire duration, and close on exit.

Edit 1:
Thank you for the suggestions on object getting destroyed. But I ensure that object is not getting destroyed.

For debugging, I had removed class/structure. Logging is now in simple C++ function calls. The file descriptor is a global variable, initialized once in main.
It does not works.
My confusion was is it something to do with the way write operations are performed on sysfs node.
Or can this be because of the number of writes are high (about 2-3 logs in 10us).

I am doing this like below, but this has an overhead of two added system calls.

```
#define TRACE_MARKER_FILE "/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker"

void logdata(pid_t tid, std::string mystring) {
    if(useLogger) {        
        std::stringstream ss;
        if (funcname.length() > 0) 
            ss << LOGTAG << mystring;

        int tempfd = open(TRACE_MARKER_FILE,  O_WRONLY);
        int count = write(tempfd, ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().length());
        if (count == 0) {
            std::cout << "Errornum: " << strerror(errno) <<std::endl;
        }
        close(tempfd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a destructor which closes the file descriptor? Do you pass or return `Logger` objects by value? Do you follow [the rules of three, five or zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? A proper [mre] would be nice to see.

Comment: Probably somewhere copy of `Logger`  is made so file is closed twice, when both instances are destroyed.

Comment: It is ensured that object is not destroyed.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I have declared Logger logger in main as a global variable.
In another thread this used as "extern Logger logger".

I am aware this is not the cleanest way of doing things and I'll do a cleanup. But there is no copy.

Comment: The file descriptor never closes unless you close it. Even with special sysfs files. Put a print statement next to where you close it. You are probably closing it accidentally.

Comment: did you decalre a destructor? Delete it. The guess is that you are copying the logger somehow

Comment: Another possibility is that some other thread called `close()` with the same value as `mFileFd` as an argument (i.e. it either called `close(mFileFd)`, or it called `close()` via some other mechanism and due to a bug just happened to pass an integer equal to `mFileFd` as the argument), and that is what led to the `Bad file descriptor` error in the Logger method.  You might want to grep your codebase for calls to `close()` and put a `printf("closing %i at %s:%i\n", fd, __FILE__, __LINE__);` before each one just to see if that is happening.

Comment: Update: I was able to resolve this issue by adding O_CLOEXEC flag while opening the file.
However I am not very clear why this worked. Could someone help me explaining this flag.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `std::ofstream` which allows for proper RAII, in other words it will open the file in your constructor, then will automatically close the file in your destructor

```cpp
class Logger {

std::ofstream mFile;

void logFromAnotherThread(std::string s) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mLogMu);
    ...
    mFile << s;
    ...
}

Logger() : mFile(SYSFS_NODE_WRITE, O_WRONLY) {
   ....
}

}
```

Comment: I've tried this as well :) 
I fall back on system calls after being unsuccessful on ofstream